# Cannot run an SQL query in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans

```
public jIFraEditSchoolNew() {
    initComponents();
    try {            
        con = new DBConnection().connect();
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        query = "select item_name from mst_item where flag != 'D'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        jCmbItemName1.addItem("");
        jCmbItemName.addItem("");
        while (rs.next()) {
            jCmbItemName.addItem(rs.getString(1));
            jCmbItemName1.addItem(rs.getString(1));
        }
        jCmbYear.addItem("");
        query = "select DISTINCT(school_year) from mst_school where flag != 'D'";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {                      \\stops at this line
            jCmbYear.addItem(rs.getString(1));
        }
        jDtePurchasedOn.setDate(new Date());
        model1 = (DefaultTableModel) jtblStitch.getModel();
        model2 = (DefaultTableModel) jtblMaterial.getModel();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
            if (!stmt.isClosed()) {
                stmt.isClosed();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a constructor of my java internal frame, the program stops when is reaches the second loop. I tried debugging the problem but did not show any error message but it keeps showing `Java Result: 1` in the output screen. I checked whether there is any thing wrong with my SQL query but it runs fine (returns one row). I can't figure out the problem, please help if anyone knows how to solve this problem!

These are information about my development environment:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201306052037)
Java: 1.7.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_17-b02
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

Comment: Does your code exit the second loop or your app crashes ?

Comment: 1) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome.

Comment: BTW - why on Earth would you have a title mentioning `JInternalFrame` when there is no `JInternalFrame` in the entire code snippet, and a comment indicating that the query fails while looping the `ResultSet`?!?  You favorite brand of tooth paste seems almost as relevant to this as an internal frame.

Comment: What makes you think it stops at that particular line?

Comment: Andrew Thompson - thanks for commmenting... the jIFraEditSchoolNew is the name of my JIternalFrame

Comment: peekskillet - when i tried debugging the project the programme was jumping from the loop statement to the finally block of the code

Comment: Tip:  Add @peeskillet (or whoever) the `@` is important.  To *notify* someone of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this.

Replace

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

By

```
PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement(query);
rs=pre.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering... the problem was that jcmbyear jcombobox was triggering a itemstatechange event which was closing the resulset.

Comment: i didn't have to use preparedStatements, all i had to do was change the Itemstatechanged event so that the resultset did not automatically close